# Where's the source-code for base::Thread

Tags: c++, mozilla, gecko

I was looking up something, and stumbled upon this code:

http://google.com/codesearch?q=kBrowserThreadNames

Where can I find the source for `base::Thread`?

(Thing is, in debugging something running under firefox.exe, I notice `Gecko_IOThread` is setting it's thread name in some kind of way and wanted to look up how.)

Comment: In case anyone's interested, this is what I was looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs(VS.71).aspx
http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/ipc/chromium/src/base/platform_thread_win.cc#48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick [Mozilla MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org) lookup seems to indicate that it's defined in [mozilla/ipc/chromium/src/base/thread.h](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/ipc/chromium/src/base/thread.h)

**Edit:**

I was also curious about the presence of Chronium code in Mozilla so I googled a bit and found this on the [blog of Benjamin Smedberg](http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/blog/2010-03-03/firefox-safe-from-plugin-crashes/) the commiter of the code:

> IPDL is a language which precisely
>   describes the messages that can be
>   passed between processes, and allows
>   developers to define a state machine
>   and error handling conditions for
>   messages and resources shared across
>   processes. **IPDL layers on top of an
>   IPC stack that Mozilla copied from the
>   Chromium codebase**

Comment: Thank you. I'm completely confused, though. What's Chromium source doing in the Mozilla repository?

Comment: @Stijn I don't know all the details but edited my post with what i was able to find.

Comment: Mozilla did not want to reinvent the wheel so it used chromium code for the IPC stuff.  It's in a compatible license, so it all works out. :)

Comment: Ah, I understand and partially agree, some strong IPC going on in Chromium. I'm only worried for the potential attack surface for security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just click your way into the code...

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cFooKvxdTls/ipc/chromium/src/base/thread.cc&q=kBrowserThreadNames&d=2